Is it possible to find the inputs $x$ such that $u(x) = K$ where $u(x)$ is the solution to a linear PDE $Lu(x) = f(x)$ without solving it?
Given a linear operator $L$ then $Lu(x) = f(x)$ is a linear PDE. Assuming there is a single solution $u(x)$ to the PDE in a bounded domain (suppose that there are some dirichlet boundary conditions enforcing this). I am interested in finding the all the values of $x$ where $u(x) = K$. Suppose that I do not know $u$ but I know $L$, $f$ and the boundary conditions. Is there a way to find all $x$'s? other than finding $u$ and then solving for the roots of $u(x) - K = 0$?

in one dimension?

I don't think anything precise can be stated without knowing the dimension and type/order of differential operator. The solution might not even be continuous!
